# Handling resignFirstResponder with Numpad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have UITextField which have keyboard type Numpad. I want to be able to hide the keyboard, when user is done.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

As numpad doesnt have a Return key to mark keyboard action as done. What can I do to pass a action to delegate resignFirstResponder

Comment: When is the user "done"? Do you provide a button for them to indicate that they're done, or do they have to type in a number of a certain length...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow users to touch the background with a transparent UIButton and then resign the responder in the button selector method, or you can add a custom button to the keyboard.

It's a bit of a complicated process to add buttons to the keyboard, but there's a good tutorial here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html